# Run custom code block when changing custom config files, similar to how Rails I18n reloading works?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like for some custom code, like `MyClass.clear_cache`, to be called in development when a YML file in `config/my_class` (like `config/my_class/foo.yml`) is changed.

It's fine if it's called on the next request rather than immediately.

I believe this is similar to how e.g. I18n and routes work.

More context: `MyClass` loads and parses big-ish files on disk (~3 MB), which is slow, so we use a singleton `MyClass.instance` that memoises (caches) the parsed data. This is fine for prod, but in development, changes to the config files should cause the memoisation to be expired.

I've found a lot of hints that this is possible using things like `app.config.file_watcher` and `Rails.configuration.to_prepare`, but I haven't yet managed to put together the pieces to achieve what I'm after.

This is for a Rails 5.2 app that isn't yet using zeitwerk, if that has any bearing. (Though I'd be interested to hear solutions that only work on later versions of Rails as well.)

Comment: Have you looked at the [guard gem](https://github.com/guard/guard)?

Comment: I did not consider guard – thanks! A downside to using it would be that it appears designed more as a command-line tool to run alongside e.g. Rails than as something that could more automatically handle this expiration.

Comment: Yeah. I usually use it anyways to run tests automatically while developing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to my own question, but a workaround I found.

Instead of trying to hook into some automatic Rails-level detection, I instead added a file watcher to my own class, like this:

```
class MyClass
  include Singleton

  def get(filename)
    reloader.execute_if_updated if Rails.env.development?

    cached_get(filename)
  end

  private

  def cached_get(filename)
    # fancy logic that uses @cache
  end

  def clear_cache
    @cache = {}
  end

  def reloader
    @reloader ||=
      Rails.configuration.file_watcher.new([], {
        Rails.root.join("config/my_class").to_s => [ "yml" ],
      }) do
        clear_cache
      end
  end
end
```

So in development, it sets up a `@reloader` on the first run, that is then memoized. And on every run, it only executes the reloader's (file watcher's) block if the config files have been modified. When the block is executed, it clears the cache.

This is good enough for my purposes but would still love to see other solutions.